# Crear un objeto con una estructura normalizada

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Tengo un servicio que me devuelve un objeto como este:

```js
[
{id: 1, name: 'Pedro', city:1, state: 1, country: 1},
{id: 2, name: 'Juan', city:12, state: 2, country: 1},
{id: 3, name: 'Ana', city:10, state: 5, country: 1},
{id: 4, name: 'Diego', city:7, state: 9, country: 1},
{id: 5, name: 'Jose', city:4, state: 2, country: 1},
{id: 6, name: 'David', city:7, state: 9, country: 1},
{id: 7, name: 'Adriana', city:1, state: 1, country: 1},
{id: 8, name: 'Jorge', city:15, state: 2, country: 1},
];
```

¿Cómo crear un objeto que quede con la siguiente estructura:

```
countries >> states >> cities >> persons
```

Comment: ¿Deseas agrupar por la propiedad `country` y así sucesivamente?

Comment: Si, que me muestre dentro de cada country sus states, dentro de cada state sus cities, y dentro de cada city sus personas(id, name)

Comment: Detalla mejor como deseas que tu objeto quede

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ejecutar el siguiente código que usa una implementación recursiva **[groupBy](https://lodash.com)** usando la librería [Lodash](https://lodash.com).

```js
_.groupByMulti = function (obj, values, context) {
        if (!values.length)
            return obj;
        var byFirst = _.groupBy(obj, values[0], context),
            rest = values.slice(1);
        for (var prop in byFirst) {
            byFirst[prop] = _.groupByMulti(byFirst[prop], rest, context);
        }
        return byFirst;
    };

    var groupedData = _.groupByMulti(getData(), ['country', 'state', 'city', 'name']);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(groupedData, null, 4));


    function getData() {
        return [
          {id: 1, name: 'Pedro', city:1, state: 1, country: 1},
          {id: 2, name: 'Juan', city:12, state: 2, country: 1},
          {id: 3, name: 'Ana', city:10, state: 5, country: 1},
          {id: 4, name: 'Diego', city:7, state: 9, country: 1},
          {id: 5, name: 'Jose', city:4, state: 2, country: 1},
          {id: 6, name: 'David', city:7, state: 9, country: 1},
          {id: 7, name: 'Adriana', city:1, state: 1, country: 1},
          {id: 8, name: 'Jorge', city:15, state: 2, country: 1},
          ];
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hola Mariano. No estoy muy familiarizado con el uso del snippet, voy a verlo.